# Proof of $\partial\partial\partial S=\partial\partial S$

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, metric-spaces

How can I prove in metric space that $$\partial\partial\partial S=\partial\partial S$$
using the proposition of the boundary below?
$$\partial S=\text{cl}S \cap \text{cl}(S^c)$$

I found that if $\partial\partial S\subseteq\text{cl}[(\partial S)^c \cup (\text{cl}(\partial S)^c)^c]$ then the proof can be finished but I can't progress further.

How can I prove it or maybe is there an easier way to complete the whole proof?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint : try to show that actually $\partial \partial F = \partial F$ if $F$ is closed.

For that, you may show that if $x\in \partial F$, there is a sequence $(x_n)$ that converges to $x$ such that $x_n\not\in \partial F$.